# Why does my function give up early?

Tags: python, list, class, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a mini program that is supposed to be a basic model of a cell's life cycle from birth to meiosis to death. Whereas the majority of it I have gotten figured out, I'm stuck at the following:

```
class cell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = random.randint(1,1000) 
        self.type = [random.choice(b)] 
        self.age = 0
        self.evos = random.randint(1,5) #<-- need to access this attr

def displayEvolutions(pop): # one of many methods, this one is a problem
    p = []
    for i in pop:
        p.append(i.evos)
        return p

community = [#a bunch of class instances]
cells_that_evolved = displayEvolutions(community)
```

It's supposed to loop through the list of class instances `community`, access their `evo` attribute, populate `cells_that_evolved` with that data, and then display that list to the user.

It should look like this:

```
cells_that_evolved = displayEvolutions(community)
print(cells_that_evolved)

[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 1, 5] #<--- 9 instances, 9 values = instance.evos
```

However, no matter what I try, it only appends the first value to the list so that list looks like this:

```
[3]
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an indentation problem:

```
def displayEvolutions(pop):
    p = []
    for i in pop:
        p.append(i.evos)
        return p
```

The first time through your loop, when `return p` is encountered, the current value of `p` is returned and the function terminates. Instead, you should return `p` after the loop completes, by unindenting that line:

```
def displayEvolutions(pop):
    p = []
    for i in pop:
        p.append(i.evos)
    return p
```

A more elegant way to write the function would be using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def displayEvolutions(pop):
    return [i.evos for i in pop]
```

Comment: And of course, a more concise way would be to use a list comprehension: `def displayEvolutions(pop): return [i.evos for i in pop]`. This has the added benefit of not allowing the possibility of indentation problems.

Comment: @SethMMorton you're right, of course - in this answer I decided to supply the simplest possible fix to a [self-described](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40713367/1) beginner.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I just figured since the list comprehension was created for precisely this purpose I thought it was worth it to introduce the concept to the OP.

Comment: @SethMMorton ok, you've twisted my arm ;-)

Comment: ha! damn, its always the simplest things. Lol thanks guys